# Can you help me find the worst-case big-O time complexity for this code?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I had a quiz in my class and didn't do so well on it. I'm looking to find out if someone can explain to me what I did wrong here - our professor is overwhelmed with office hours as we moved online due to COVID-19 so I thought I'd post here as I have yet to hear a response.

```
def functionC(L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if L[i] == i:
            v = L.pop(i)
            L.insert(i, 2*v)
    return
```

I supplied the following answer:

> The above function is O(n) because the for-loop grows with the size of
>   L. The pop and insert functions are both constant time.

the word time is crossed out, but there is no other explanation as to why I received 6/10 for the question. What did I get wrong in this and why?

Here is an image of the question and my answer to prove the quiz has already been graded and handed back.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Popping from and inserting into the middle of an array is `O(N)` time in terms of the length of the array. Thus overall time complexity is `O(N^2)`. You only get `O(1)` pop and insert when working with the end of the array, since the rest of the elements don't have to be shifted, but it's `O(N)` elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into this python wiki [time-complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) document, you will see the complexity of ***Pop intermediate*** and ***insert*** are listed as **O(n)** which in turns makes the above code **O(n^2)**